# How to force compiler error when no value is explicitly returned from function

Tags: c++, gcc

One of the most common errors I make is that I forget to return the result from a method/function, and the compiler doesn't complain.

How can I make GCC raise a compilation error if no result is returned? (these are usually trivial situations, where there is no return statement in a method)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `-Wreturn-type` (I would recommend at least `-Wall`, maybe also `-Wextra`). It gives a warning when you don't return a value; you can use `-Werror` to make it into an error.

Comment: I'd just go for -Wall -Wextra nearly always (only exception is 3rd party code giving warnings you do not want fix). Basically everything warned about by these is something you shouldn't be doing in quality code anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Compile with the `-Wall -Werror` flags. This will produce an error:

> error: no return statement in function returning non-void

`-Wall` by itself only produces a warning.

I recommend compiling with `-Wextra` too.

Answer (score 1):

`g++ -Werror main.cpp -o main` Warnings as errors! and -Wall helps too